# Would gradient boosting machines benefit from adaptive learning rates?

Tags: neural-networks, boosting

In deep learning, a big deal is made about optimizing an adaptive learning rate. There are [numerous popular adaptive learning rate algorithms](https://towardsdatascience.com/gradient-descent-algorithms-and-adaptive-learning-rate-adjustment-methods-79c701b086be).

The hyperparameters for [all of the leading gradient boosting machines](https://towardsdatascience.com/catboost-vs-light-gbm-vs-xgboost-5f93620723db), by contrast, involve setting only a fixed learning rate. Intuitively, it could make sense to instead use a decreasing learning rate or possibly a hill-shaped learning rate.

Is there any obvious mechanical limitation in how GBMs are implemented that would make an adaptive learning rate difficult? If not, is there a simple argument for why a constant rate makes more sense for a GBM than for deep learning?

UPDATE: [Relevant discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1257) in the context of LightGBM.

Comment: I think that it is almost given that a future GBM algorithm will use adaptive learning rates in the future. That being said, notice that the learning rate $\eta$ is akin to a regularisation parameter too, so we would need to explain this in terms of regularisation too. It is not exactly as step in function in a multi-dimensional linear space we are taking but rather a step in the functional space.